# loop for linear model execution with changing vars names and data sets

Tags: r, loops, linear-regression

I'm working on a task that I would like to automate,I'm new to looping and variables assigments so any help will be great.
The task has two steps: first get few data set with one different character from each other and second apply an lm model with variables that are also have one different character that is in tendem with the dataset name.For example : use data set with the name `SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day**3**_BaseLine` and apply a lm that contains varirables like `IsDepositorDay**3**` and `IsDueDay**3**` . I have about 10 data sets and 50 variables that I would like to automate so I tried to use this code based on an answare from this site but I get an error.

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
    "    eval(parse(text = paste0("SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day", i, "_BaseLine<-maindata"))
        f"

# Here is my code
f <- NA # first I reset f
index <- 1 # this will be the index
for(i in c(3,10){ #3,10 are the only charcter that changes in the data sets and in vars names.
    var[i]<-paste("IsDepositorDay",i,sep="")
    eval(parse(text = "var[i]"))
    maindata<-paste("SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day",i,"_BaseLine",sep="")
    eval(parse(text = paste0("SF_FinalviewQ3_2013_Day", i, "_BaseLine<-maindata"))
    f[index]<-lm(IsDepositorDay180~ var1,data=maindata)
    index <- index + 1
}
```

How can I solve it?

```
#per a request to make my example reproducible i did the following changes:
dat1 <- read.table(text = " target birds_1   wolfs_1     snakes_1
         0        3        9         7
         1        3        8         4
         1        1        2         8 ",header = TRUE)
dat2 <- read.table(text = " target birds_2    wolfs_2     snakes_2
         1        3        2         4
         0        8        8         3
         5        1        2         8  ",header = TRUE)


  f <- NA # first I reset f
index <- 1 # this will be the index
for(i in c(1,2)){ #1,2 are the only charcter that changes in the data sets and in vars names.
    birds_[i]<-paste("birds_",i,sep="")
    wolfs_[i]<-paste("wolfs_",i,sep="")
    snakes_[i]<-paste("snakes_",i,sep="")
    eval(parse(text = "birds_[i]"))
    eval(parse(text = "wolfs_[i]"))
    eval(parse(text = "snakes_[i]"))
    maindata<-paste("dat",i,sep="")
    eval(parse(text = paste0("dat", i, "<-maindata"))
         f[index]<-lm(target~ birds_[i]+snakes_[i],data=maindata)
         index <- index + 1
}
```

Comment: Can you please make your example reproducible? The usage of `eval(parse(x))` feels a bit disturbing. I'm positive there's a better way of constructing a dataset and/or formula, but it would help if you help us first.

Comment: Hello Roman, I added an example below my original text.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the lm objects can be kept in a list as following. The column that is not included in the formula is removed to keep it simple.

```
# way 1 with loop    
f <- list()
dat <- list(dat1, dat2)
for(i in 1:2) f[[i]] <- lm(target ~ ., data = dat[[i]][,-3])

# way 2 with lapply
dat <- list(dat1[,-3], dat2[,-3])
lapply(dat, lm, formula = target ~ .)

[[1]]

Call:
FUN(formula = ..1, data = X[[1L]])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      birds_1     snakes_1  
     4.3333      -0.6667      -0.3333  


[[2]]

Call:
FUN(formula = ..1, data = X[[2L]])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      birds_2     snakes_2  
     -3            0            1
```

Some recommendations of your set up would be

- keep the column name of dependent variable (target in your example) the same
- keep the same number of independent variables (and even better in the same order)

Then the formula can be easy to set up and key variables (coefficients...) would  also easy to extract.

Comment: Thanks Jaehyeon Kim, Can you tell me what does [[i]] means?

Comment: It is just subsetting elements of f. f has two elements and [[i]] extracts the data frame while [i] extracts a list, which might not accepted by lm().